# Как точно вывести время компиляции?

Tags: c++, компиляция, время

Чтобы вплоть до секунд. Где-то писали, что это все решается с помощью библиотеки `<ctime>` и временным типом `time_t`, но не работает

```
int main()
{

    time_t start= time(0);
    char mas[80] = {'c', 'a', 's', 't', 'l', 'e', 'v', 'a', 'n', 'i','a'  }; 

    char *p;
    p=mas;

    cout << p << endl;
    cout << (time(0)-start) << " минут" << endl;
}
```

Я пробовал в

```
(time(0)-start)
```

Умножать на 60 и 3600, но в итоге все равно выдает 0, но я не уверен, что программа компилится за 0 секунд? Или проблема в том, что я прошу вернуть в этом коде мне целочисленный тип? Тогда каково решение?

Comment: Ваш пример показывает, как узнать время выполнения скрипта, а не его компиляции.

Comment: Ладно, пусть будет так. Как правильно тогда?

Comment: Засечь время до компиляции, скомпилировать, от текущего времени отнять время, которое засекали. Есть много способов это сделать, от обычного самописного скрипта до специализированных инструментов, но я с C++ не работаю, поэтому ничего не посоветую - подождите ответ знатоков.

Comment: `time()` возвращает время **в СЕКУНДАХ** (см. [man 2 time](https://linux.die.net/man/2/time)). Поэтому и результат -- 0. Почитайте man-ы других функций, например, [man 3 clock](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock), [man 2 gettimeofday](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday), [man 2 clock_gettime](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime) и SEE ALSO в них. Думаю, что-то для себя подберете. Что же касается **собственно времени компиляции**, то проще всего запустить компилятор в командной строке через утилиту `time`. Как-то так: `time gcc .....`

Comment: И всё-таки, какое время Вам нужно: компиляции или выполнения? В заголовке вопроса одно, в теле другое.

Comment: Visual Studio умеет показывать время компиляции, к примеру.

Comment: Время, затраченное на работу найти

Comment: @avp, не совсем понятно, что ты имеешь ввиду, "возвращает В СЕКУНДАХ, поэтому и результат 0) В man 2 time тоже не нашел ответа.

Comment: Имеется в виду, что `time` возвращает целое число секунд, прошедших с какой-то даты и если программа работала меньше полсекунды, то скорее всего оба вызова `time` вернут одно и то же число и их разность будет равна нулю.

Comment: @diraria, в основном верно, только не *с какой-то даты*, а совершенно определенно с 1 января 1970 года.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Время **выполнения** программы:

1. C++11 способ. Получаем два времени через [`chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now), вычитаем их. Получаем временной интервал ([`chrono::duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)). Временной интервал хранит тип тика и число тиков. В качестве типа тика могут быть `секунды`, `миллисекунды` и другие. Далее через [`chrono::duration_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) приводим этот временной интервал к временному интервалу с типом тика `миллисекунды`. И с помощью метода [`count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count) получаем число миллисекунд.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <chrono>
   using namespace std;

   int main() {
       auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

       // здесь код, например:
       for (int i = 0; i < 1e8; ++i) {}

       auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
       double seconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() / 1000.0;
       printf("Программа работала %.3f секунд\n", seconds);
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Через [`clock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Clock) и [`CLOCKS_PER_SEC`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/CLOCKS_PER_SEC):

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   int main() {
       // здесь код, например:
       for (int i = 0; i < 1e8; ++i) {}

       double seconds = clock() / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
       printf("Программа работала %.3f секунд\n", seconds);
   }
   ```

Время **компиляции** программы:

В linux при компиляции из командной строки можно воспользоваться утилитой [`time`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix)):

```
% time g++ main.cpp
g++ main.cpp  0,42s user 0,05s system 99% cpu 0,470 total
```

Либо можно компилировать с аргументом `-ftime-report`, это выдаст статистику времени компилирования, общее время будет в последней строчке

```
g++ -ftime-report main.cpp
```

Comment: Утилита `time` — это только для Unix-систем и только для компиляции из-под командной строки.

Comment: Впрочем, написать подобную утилиту самостоятельно по идее не должно быть большой проблемой. Например, на основе первой части ответа.

Comment: Ну, для реализации утилиты `time` лучше почитать  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html (и как всегда SEE ALSO там)

Comment: VladD, а кто-то компилит иначе?

Comment: @VlaD , что это значит? " 
Утилита time — это только для Unix-систем и только для компиляции из-под командной строки." - Если для Unix, значит не для Windows?

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing да, в Windows такой программы нет, по крайней мере в Windows 8 и младше. Но эта программа используется только для измерения времени компиляции, вам же надо время выполнения?

Comment: @bukkojot: Ну, некоторые люди используют IDE. Я когда-то использовал KDevelop.

Comment: @VlaD, а мне лично проще написать gcc *.c, а учитывая, что Студию под виндой я так и не завел, то компиляю виндовые бинарники под линуксом, чем несказанно доволен.

Comment: @bukkojot: Компиляция-то не сложная, но вот как вы живёте без подсказок редактора и автодополнения? И gdb без UI-оболочки тоже не очень удобно использовать, разве нет?

Comment: @VlaD, gdb без UI-оболочки очень удобен, особенно когда надо что-то быстро отдебажить на сервере, так как свеженаписанный код почему-то начал крешится, хотя до этого все отлично работало. Подсказки редактора достаточно сомнительное занятие, подсветка же есть везде. Единственное, чего мне порой нехватает, так это разворачивания структурок, так как я порой забываю называния полей и не могу вспомнить "stop_btn" или "btn_stop" нужно ли писать. Да, быть может это не всем подходит, но тормоза Студии и ее засирание системы терпеть точно не собираюсь. Сам для написания кода использую mc и всем доволен

Comment: @Vlad, что даст gcc *c. ? В  интернете ничего толкового не нашел, что оно делает? Я просто не в курсе.

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing, `gcc *.c` это команда терминала, которая компилирует все файлы в текущей директории с расширением `.c` (то есть файлы на языке Си). Если вы пишите и компилируете код в IDE (Visual Studio, CLion, ...) и вам нравится, то можно не использовать эту команду.

Comment: @diraria , нет, Vim

Comment: А, тогда желательно разобраться как работает эта команда. В ней символ `*` имеет особый смысл, вкратце можно почитать [тут](https://vds-admin.ru/shell-scripting/sluzhebnye-simvoly#pattern_)

Comment: @bukkojot: Хм. У меня так получалось только с маленькими проектами, а когда в проекте несколько тысяч файлов, только чтобы найти, где же определён данный класс, с одним только grep'ом мне было сложно. У вас, должно быть, лучше память, чем у меня.

Answer (score 1):

Для измерения времени компиляции есть специальная библиотека для cmake: [metabench](https://github.com/ldionne/metabench). 
Позволяет измерить время компиляции отдельного фрагмента файла. Принцип действия прост: сначала компилируется файл без этого фрагмента, затем - с ним (с помощью макросов). Разница во времени - время компиляции этого фрагмента. Естественно, тестируемый фрагмент должен быть независимым.

Результаты выводятся в разных вариантах, в том числе в виде html с графиками.

Подробностей я уже не помню, в проекте есть примеры. Под Windows точно работает с mingw64, с другими не пробовал.