# Отсчет времени от начала программы

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Создаю маленькую программу. Нужно, чтобы в переменную `int timer;` записывалось время(в секундах) от начала программы, как это сделать?

Comment: связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/713452/227016

Comment: это немного не то что я хотел, мне надо что бы ввелся таймер от начала и без конца

Comment: Вам не надо использовать таймер, есть класс `DateTime`. Вызовем `System::DateTime.Now` при запуске. Или же использовать прекрасный класс `Stopwatch`.

Comment: Прошу опять пример :D, сорян недавно только вникся в программирование

Comment: @SЌĬPクラス: Дополните вопрос что бы было более понятно что вы хотите получить за время, время выполнения, или же время работы программы?

Comment: Скажем так нужно что бы начался секундомер после нажатия на картинку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея в том, что в нулевой момент надо запомнить текущее время, а любой другой взять разницу между текущим и запомненым.

```
#include <time.h>

time_t zeroTime = time(0);

int elapsedSeconds()
{
    return time(0) - zeroTime;
}

int main(...) 
{
    sleep(10);
    std::cout << elapsedSeconds();
}
```

Можно сделать классом

```
class ElapsedTime
{
public:
    ElapsedTime() 
        : zeroTime(time(0))
    {
    }
    int elapsed()
    {
        return time(0) - zeroTime;
    }
private:
    time_t zeroTime;
};

ElapsedTime someWhereInCode()
{
    ElapsedTime timer;
    ....
    execVeryLongOperation();
    ...
    return ElapsedTime 
}


void main()
{
    ElapsedTime timer = someWhereInCode();
    std::cout << timer.elapsed();

}
```